# After update, my printer will not work

Tags: printing, hp

I've been successfully using an HP Deskjet 1000 j100 for some time now.  The other day, I updated my system (automatic) and my printer stopped working.  I get the error message "Filter Failed"

I can't find anything on the HP site about this.

Is there something that changed?  Is there an obvious workaround?

Comment: Add details: What version of **Ubuntu**? (eg. 12.04, 13.04) .. and **32-bit** or **64-bit**? What version of **HPLIP** is currently installed? (**Ctrl-Alt-T**, then type **`dpkg -l hplip`**)

Comment: Installed Ubuntu 13.04, 32-bit, HPLIP 3.13.3-1

Comment: Turn printer off, unplug USB cord, delete printer/queue (under Ubuntu), turn back on (wait 10 seconds), and plug back in. This should auto-create a new print queue. *Report back ..*

Comment: Tried all of that with no success.  As soon as I do a ctrl-P, the window shows immediately with this comment:  "Filter Failed"

Comment: Fixed !!  Turned the printer off again.  left it off for 30 minutes and plugged everything back in.  Works great.  Thanks for your time, David6

Comment: Glad it works. Don't forget to go to http://localhost:631 in your browser when problems occur. That's the CUPS web interface. It will let you send test pages and do all sorts of printer and print queue maintenance.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue after an performing an update to Ubuntu 16.04. The printer was an HP Officejet Pro 8610. Printer stopped, re. no filter.
Using Synaptic package manager, I found only one hplip program installed after the update. I installed two others and everything works again. Needed programs are hplip, hplip data & hplip doc.